# Simple ASP.NET app for testing in Azure

Tags: asp.net

I am attempting to create and test our deployment strategy in Azure and I am doing that by deploying a web API and a web app that connects to it. Now I know next to nothing about web programming. I've searched for hours for a simple hello world style application and found examples with logins, complex structures, and databases. No. I want an API that gives you a string and a web app that fetches that string and displays it. Simple.

I created two projects in Visual Studio using their ASP.NET templates, and it generated over 500 files for me.
In the API project I setup a controller for my test:

```
using System.Web.Http;
namespace ApiTest1.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/TestApi/v1_0")]
    public class TestAPIController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("")]
        public string Get()
        {
            return "Test API v1.0";
        }

        [Route("{id}")]
        public string Get(string id)
        {
            return "Test API v1.0 " + id;
        }
    }
}
```

In the app project I replaced the login.cshtml with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test Web App</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h2>Test App 1</h2>

    <button type="button" onclick="getApiString2()">Get Result</button>

    <p>API result</p>
    <p id="testApiResult"></p>

    <script>
    function getApiString2()
    {
        var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "http://webapitest1.azurewebsites.net/api/TestAPI/v1_0";

        xmlHttp.open("GET", url, false); // false for synchronous request
        xmlHttp.send(null);

        document.getElementById("testApiResult").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This worked when I just ran the two projects (with an adjustment to the URL). When I deploy these to Azure I look in the F12 tools and find

```
SEC7120: Origin http://webapptest1.azurewebsites.net not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.
File: Login
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
File: Login
SCRIPT5022: NetworkError
File: Login, Line: 61, Column: 9
```

Is there some security in Azure that I need to push through? Are those 500+ other files in the projects getting in the way? Or maybe someone would be kind enough to provide a truly simple example?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need to enable CORS support as several tutorials even in [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Enable CORS

You should enable CORS for you API project as it is deployed under a different domain. Read more about [CORS headers here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). I would use [this Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors) to enable CORS on your Web API project. Please see an excellent tutorial on how to use the package [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api).

Just for example, simple response CORS headers may look like that:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com
```

---

### ASP.NET MVC + Web API side-by-side

If you wanted just a simple ASP.NET MVC + Web API app you could host them side-by-side in a single web application and under the same domain name, with no need to enable CORS header. Just make sure you pick the right project template that would add necessary dependencies and initial configs for you:

**For full .NET Framework**

Any of these would work. They do create a lot of stuff that you probably wouldn't need. That's why I usually go for Empty, it still has some initial configuration. Maybe it would work for you too.

[image]

**For .NET Core**

[image]